# Mouse motion makes frame disappear in Overlay of long ListPlots

Tags: graphics, interface

Using M9, OSX 10.8.4,  most parts of the `Frame` in the following overlay disappear (also partially occluding some `FrameTicks`) when scrolling the mouse after the output is generated.

Note the 10,000: the issue doesn't occur for much smaller `ListPlot` arguments.

Can anyone replicate?

```
    With[{t = Table[Random[], {10000}]},
 Overlay[{
     ListPlot[t, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, Axes -> False, 
    FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
    ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All],
     ListPlot[t+1, 
    Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, Axes -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Darker@Red, FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
    FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Darker@Red}, 
    Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 800, 
    PlotRange -> All]}]
 ]
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Comment: @Kuba, note edit, NDifferenceDelta --> t+1 (makes no difference, and no it's based on Partition, no package)

Comment: Ok, well, no problem on Win7 V9

Comment: I tried on Mac OS X 10.7.5 V9, and if I understand what you mean, it looked fine. (I.e. nothing disappeared when I moved mouse after output).  Mouse is inaccurate, trackpad of PowerBook is what I used to move.  But I see both blue and red unlike picture above.

Comment: @alancalvitti WAIT!!! On further playing with it, I am now seeing the weird disappearing frame behavior. The system seems quite sluggish too.

Comment: @alancalvitti I think I figured it out. Check your magnification. The problem is not there when I am at 100% or 75% magnification, but it is there at 125% and 150%.  I can repeatedly make the behavior appear and  disappear by changing it.

Comment: @AndyMobley, agreed, I usually set it at 125 or 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of the problem. I don't know why it is happening exactly though, but it seems that a workaround is simply to keep the `Magnification` at or below 100%.

```
    SetAttributes[setOpt, Listable]; 
    setOpt[cell_, mag_] := SetOptions[cell, Magnification -> mag];

    probCell = 
     With[{t = Table[Random[], {10000}]}, 
      Overlay[{ListPlot[t, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
         Axes -> False, 
         FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}, 
         PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
         ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All], 
        ListPlot[t + 1, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
         Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Darker@Red, 
         FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
         FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Darker@Red}, 
         Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 800, 
        PlotRange -> All]}]]

    nb = CreateDocument[{probCell, probCell, probCell, probCell, 
        probCell}];
    setOpt[Cells[nb], {0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5}];
```

[image: Magnification of Cells]

Comment: Unfortunately to drill down on fine details we use higher magnification. Will report to WRI tech.

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks for reporting this. I am sure that it will help me sometime in the future because I almost always use >100%.  Call it middle age beginnings of presbyopia. It was only luck that I saw what seemed to be causing it.